# Google Chrome Strikes Out the entire https URL

Tags: google-chrome, browser, https

I am using Google Chrome Browser v60 on Windows 7 64 bit. On a desktop PC on one of my LAN Computers I have installed Oracle 12c. It comes with its own Web Based Enterprise Manager that can be accessed at https://Hostname:5500/em
The site uses HTTPS but is not secure. I was expecting Google Chrome to strikeout the https part of the URL in the browser.

However to my surprise, Chrome strikes out the entire URL from one end to other, as seen in this screenshot. What does this mean? Why would chrome strike out the entire URL? Does it have any different meaning that striking out only the ‘https’ part?

I searched the internet, some forums talk about relevance with SEO Chrome Extension, however I have no extensions installed in Chrome.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is typical behaviour if for some reason Chrome decides that the https certificate presented by the web server is not "good enough" to be trusted.

It can be expired, or not strong enough, or not signed by somebody trusted by Chrome.  In this case the default setup of the webserver most likely creates its own, so-called self-signed certificate which by definition is untrusted (and can be hijacked by anyone), so Chrome flags it as such.

If you are *certain* that there is nobody intercepting your communication with that server, then continue communication, but be aware that it does not have the normal security guarantee that https usually implies.